# Hexadecimal Slide Numbers in PowerPoint

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, slide, presentation

Is it possible to have my power point slides numbered in hexadecimal?
I know it sounds crazy, but I wanted to give a substile nerdy feel to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't have PPT do this for you automatically, but you could run a little code that adds a text box to each slide and in the text box, put the slide's number, converted to hex.

Something like so:

```
Dim oSl as Slide
Dim oSh as Shape

For each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slide
  Call DeleteHexNumber(oSl)
  ' change coordinates to suit:
  Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal,10,10,200,50)
  Osh.Tags.Add "HexNumber", "Whatever"
  With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = Cstr(Hex(oSl.SlideNumber))
  End With
Next

Sub DeleteHexNumber(oSl as Slide)
  Dim oSh as Shape
  Dim x as Long 
  For x = oSl.Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
    if Len(oSl.Shapes(x).Tags("HexNumber")) > 0 Then
        oSl.Shapes(x).Delete
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

As edited:
Now it tags the page number shape when it creates it but before it creates it, it looks for any existing page number shapes (by checking for matching tags) and deletes them first.

Comment: If I run the script again, another set of text boxes are created. Is there a way to find and remove all exiting text boxes or update the existing text boxes?